# List entries which have no category assigned

Tags: channel-entries, categories, channel, loop

Anyone know how to do this?

Obviously I can pass in a category ID into the channel loop to get entries within that specific category. But I'd like to get a list of all entries that don't currently have any categories assigned to them.

This purely requried as a reference, I've done a massive import and need to generate a working list so my editoiral guys can go in and categorise those entries which aren't assigned to anything.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe?
{exp:channel:entries category_group="not 1|2|3|4"}

Comment: Damnit, that's so obvious. Thanks!